# Qt Symbian Memory, unexpected application termination on device

Tags: memory-leaks, symbian

Recently I did develop a Symbian application. In Qt simulator it works perfect but in actual device the application terminates unexpectedly. I suspect this is a memory leak issue. 
Already i have followed all possible(following) memory cleaning mechanisms:

- Creating new objects as pointers.
- deleting the objects after use
- using 'delete' keyword. using deleteLater() function on ui objects.

But still the application terminates on the device.

please suggest me possible solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the Heap and/or Stack sizes using the EPOCHEAPSIZE and EPOCSTACKSIZE statements in your .PRO file

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-platform-notes.html#stack-and-heap-size

Although it may depend on which Qt SDK you are using as the documentation now states that the Qt toolchain already sets these to the maximum possible values.